# part of property and methods of selenium IWebElement not working with geckodriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

My former question seems gone silence, so I would like to post a new question and get my old question deleted.
I am writing a test for a website in c#, the code ran perfectly when using chrome driver, however things start to go wrong when I tried to run the same code using geckodriver.

Here is the log info

```
Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Stacktrace:       
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at SeleniumExtras.PageObjects.WebElementProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Reflection.DispatchProxyGenerator.Invoke(Object[] args)
       at generatedProxy_1.get_Displayed()
       at testAuto.Framework.Pages.Dashboard.DashboardPage.Logged_in() in "Path to code file":line 350
```

The "Path to code file" is the path to the file where the code is.

Here is the code where it indicates the error

```
public void Logged_in()
{           
    Assert.True(LogOut.Displayed);
}
```

Code to find log out button

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "a[href *= '/Private/Logout']")]
private IWebElement LogOut;
```

Corresponding  HTML part of log out button

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/Private/Logout.aspx" target="_self">
      Log out
    </a>
  </li>
<ul>
```

I don't have control over the html part, so suggestion regarding the method would be appreciated. Besides, I have code that wait for the page to get fully loaded before I perform that assertion. The version of geckodriver is 0.23.0


More Info:

I tried to parse the style value but the "GetAttribute()" falls into similar exception too. 

Here is the log file

```
Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Stacktrace:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at SeleniumExtras.PageObjects.WebElementProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args)
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Reflection.DispatchProxyGenerator.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at generatedProxy_1.GetAttribute(String )
   at testAuto.Framework.Helper.IsElemVisible(IWebElement element) in "Path to code file":line 107
   at testAuto.Implementation.dashboardSpec.Verify_log_in() in "Path to code file":line 120
```